# brew install homebrew/php/php56 giving me an error

Tags: php, linux, homebrew

[image]

Hi I am trying to install homebrew php56 on ubuntu 14.04
I installed php 5.6 and apache2 and other dependencies of installation like perl, curl , etc.

But still I am getting this error.

Comment: Homebrew? You mean the homebrew package manager **for OS X**?! How'd you get that onto Ubuntu in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

That's rather a freaky way — install something on Ubuntu Linux through homebrew — it's actually should not work.

You'd better use apt package manager. You can install php-5.6 binaries from PPA:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5
```